# Is there an easy way to clean to the SAS environment between projects?

Tags: sas, environment, resource-cleanup

I want to make sure that there are no macro vars in existance after running one project and starting the next. I've found code that claims to do this but it also cleans the prompt vars that are defind in the new project making them useless.

Surely getting a clean environment when loading a project is pretty basic stuff?

Comment: Why not just run the code in a new SAS session?  How are you submitting your code? Since you mentioned "prompts" are you using something like Enterprise Guide to submit your SAS code?

Comment: Why not just use the code you found but tell it to NOT remove the macro variables you know you want to keep?

Comment: Are you using Enterprise Guide?  Unfortunately, prompt values are macro variables. And EG uses macro variables for a lot of other purposes.  So if you simply delete all macro variables, you can have problems like this. Easiest way to get a fresh environment from EG is to disconnect from the server and then reconnect. You can do it without quitting EG, by right-click on the server name.